# How to make pojo class based on table header?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, pojo

I have table which can be customised like the headers of table are also changeble and can add rows and columns in the table. According to that table   dynamically create a pojo class and the fields are based on these table headers at run time so that i can save it to database(mongodb).

I am searching for this and get nothing yet.
like i have a table with these headers.

> | Name | Rollnumber | class|

these header's name are customizable. SO the pojo class should be generated at run time.
like

```
class Student
  {
    private name;
    private rollnumber;
    private class;
    //getter and setter
    }
```

if the headers of the table changed then the pojo class should also be changed.

Comment: It is called `mapping`

Comment: Read more about object-relational mapping.

Comment: sorry. but i have changed my question

Comment: What is the purpose of POJO in your case. If you want to make it generic, read Tabel metadata and write utility class on this metadata reader, with methods same as ORM, such as save, read, delete, finder if you need any.

Comment: how to save the table data without modal?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to keep dynamic records. Some may have certain attributes, and some may not, is that correct?

You cannot create a pojo dynamically, but you can change the dimensions of your data structure (transforming the table columns into rows, as only rows can be dynamic)

```
class Student {
    private String name;
    private String rollnumber;
    private String class;

    // Getters & Setters for the static fields 
}

class Field {
    private String fieldName;
    private String dataType; // Can enhance using an enum

    // Getters & Setters
}

class StudentField {
    private Student student;
    private Field field;
    private String value;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

This way, you can create a dynamic field and persist in "Field", and then map the created fields dynamically with the Student in "StudentField".

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've used for changeable column names is to restructure my collection like this:

```
{
  [
    {
      "name": "my-name",
      "datatype": "my-datatype",
      "display-name": "column-name1",
      "value":"value"
    },  
    {
      "name": "my-name2",
      "datatype": "my-datatype2",
      "display-name": "column-name2",
      "value":"value2"
    }
  ],
  [ ... ]
}
```

The display name will of course be changeable, but the name will not.
You can then make a 'generic pojo' just with those four fields.